# Why doesn't Gnus natively support Atom feeds?

Tags: gnus

This seems quite strange to me, because Gnus is very widely used, and so are Atom feeds. Is there any ideological reason perhaps?

Comment: No ideological reason, it's just a question of someone doing the required work. There is now an attempt being reviewed for inclusion: https://bugs.gnu.org/64202

Comment: You should make this comment an answer, I would accept it!

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any ideological reason perhaps?

No, it's just a question of doing the required work.

In fact, Daniel Semyonov has already worked on adding Atom support to Gnus: https://bugs.gnu.org/64202

It looks like the review process stalled a bit, but I don't see any blockers, and you should feel free to ping the discussion (by emailing the address listed at the top of the report) as a reminder :).